# Properties of $>$ for rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This question comes from an introductory undergraduate course in Analysis. We have just started from defining the set of rational numbers and then we will construct the set of real numbers. We define the order relation "$> $" on the set of rationals as follows: $$(\frac{a}{b})>(\frac{c}{d})\Leftrightarrow (ad-bc)\in \mathbb{N}$$. I am trying to prove that the set of rationals with this order relation is an ordered set. I want to prove the transitive property, by doing the following: $$(\frac{a}{b})>(\frac{c}{d})\Leftrightarrow (ad-bc)\in \mathbb{N}$$

$$(\frac{c}{d})>(\frac{e}{f})\Leftrightarrow (cf-de)\in \mathbb{N}$$. I need to show that:
$$(\frac{a}{b})>(\frac{e}{f}), i.e\ (af-be)\in \mathbb{N}$$
I tried to prove the last statement, by saying that $(ad-bc)(cf-de)=(acdf-adde-bccf+bcde)\in \mathbb{N}$. Then, I didn't really what do next. Any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: unless you suppose that the denominators are all positive, this may not be an order relation. So you probably need to use $b,d,f > 0$ somewhere in the proof.

Answer (score 2):

You nee to use transitivity of $<$ for integers. Then from $ad>bc$ you have  $adf>bcf>bde$. Hence $af>be$.

Answer (score 0):

This question cannot be answered since a claim used to construct the question is false. In particular, the definition of ">" used is not an order relation since, for instance, if we let $a,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b,d\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ and restrict $a=0, c>0, b<0, d>0$ we have that $$0d-bc=-bc\in\mathbb{N}$$ while $$\frac{0}{b}=0\not>\frac{c}{d}$$ a contradiction.